# when I remove this "WORD 13" it is working fine, but I want to move the whole 'str1

Tags: string, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

```
include irvine32.inc

.data
str1 WORD 13
     BYTE 'Source String',0
desti BYTE 80 DUP(?)

.code
main PROC
mov esi,offset str1
inc esi
mov edi,offset desti
call dumpregs
mov ecx, lengthof str1
rep movsb

mov edx,offset desti
call WriteString
call crlf

exit 
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Presumably you will have to adjust `lengthof str1`.

Answer (score 1):

What does MASM's `lengthof` calculate?  Just the 2-byte `word` and ignore the `byte` array on a separate line?

You could do `byte 13, 0, 'Source String',0` to get the same data bytes in memory but have MASM treat the whole thing as one "variable".

Or you could put a label at the end and calculate the size yourself with `str1_len equ end-start` instead of relying on MASM's magic that treats labelled data specially as a "variable".

Any time you want to do anything that isn't exactly what MASM expects, you typically have to work around it.  e.g. `dword ptr` to load 4 bytes from a "variable" that was declared with a different size.